# Подскажите как сохранить холст fabric js в базу данных?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, fabricjs

Всем привет, вопрос такой, как сохранить холст fabric-js в базу данных mysql, т.е, человек регистрируется на сайте, после чего попадает на страницу конструктора лого который сделан на fabric-js, нарисовал человек логотип себе, и хочет сохранить его в личном кабинете, как мне сделать что бы по клику он сохранял холст в базе данных и потом мог его допустим от редактировать снова.
Я читал их документацию, там сказанно про сериализацию и десериализацию, я получаю json холста, а как его поместить в базу данных никак не могу понять, уже неделю мучаюсь, прощу помощи!
Спасибо всем)

Comment: Что используете для сохранения в базу? Покажите свой код.

Answer (score 0):

На стороне `JS` для готово холста, после клика "Сохранить" используешь метод `toJSON` у `canvas`, он отдаст тебе валидную JSON строку и передаешь эту строку на сервер.

На стороне сервера создаешь таблицу `user_logo`, где поле `logo` типа `JSON`, и привязка к юзеру `user_id`.

А затем уже записываешь отправленные данные в эту таблицу.

При загрузке лого, на стороне `JS` используешь метод `loadFromJSON(json, function(){})` у `canvas`, где `json` валидный JSON из базы, который тоже можешь получить из сервера.

Comment: У меня нет в базе данных типа json, это связанно с версией  mysql?

Comment: да, можно в TEXT запихать, а уже скриптом эту строку в JSON

Comment: По клику я получаю json строку вашим методом, правильно ли выглядит она 
"{objects: Array(1), background: "", backgroundImage: {…}}" весь текст не входит сюда просто, символов много пишет)
В базе сделал поле)

Comment: Вот самы сложный для меня процесс "А затем уже записываешь отправленные данные в эту таблицу." как это делать ?
Я получается через ajax должен отправить строку в базу
function myFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'logo_json.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { hallo_str: JSON.stringify(str_json) },

    });     
   

}

Comment: Я использую jquery просто)

Comment: @Михаил все правильно с $.ajax описали, теперь все ясно? где еще подсказать?)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое))
А как получается php обработчик должен выглядеть?
т.е я использую там INSERT INTO, а как мне смогу строку получить в этот php файл и записать в переменную?)

Comment: @Михаил если голый PHP, то можно `$_REQUEST['hallo_str']` или `$_POST['hallo_str']`

Comment: спасибо большое))

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, пишет ошибку "Undefined index: hallo_str in /opt/lampp/htdocs/hallo_json.php on line 3" подскажите почему так?
Php такой
"<?php require "db/db_connect.php";?>
<?php
    $logo = $_REQUEST['hallo_str'];



$sql = "INSERT INTO users (userlogo)
VALUES ('$logo')";
?>"

Comment: `if (isset($_POST["hallo_str"]) && !empty($_POST["hallo_str"])) {
    
}` вот условие такое нужно примерно, видимо `hallo_str` не приходит

Comment: а в самом условии я пишу добавление получается в базу insert?

Comment: да, если передается это поле, то запись в базу

Comment: Вот так правильно
<?php

$data = $_POST["hallo_str"];

if (isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (userlogo)
VALUES ('$data')";
 }



?>

Comment: @Михаил а где привязка к юзеру? как определяете какой пользователь отправил?)  и тут вот так вроде должно быть VALUES ('{$data}')

Comment: аааа, я использую библиотеку php redbean для регистрации и авторизции пользователя, а как мне получить привязку к пользователю, я просто думал что пользователь авторизован, это он и совершает действие )

Comment: это ORM для взаимодействия с БД. Когда пользователь авторизуется, надо куда-нибудь это записать на сервере, обычно идет привязка к сессии. Запишите ID авторизованного юзера в его сессию, после успешной авторизации